# Continuous charging and discharging notifications at 100% charge

Tags: sound, power-management, battery, notification

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I use an old laptop with a crappy battery, so I like to keep it plugged in all the time. However when I am at 100% charge, Ubuntu enters a cycle between "Charging" and "Fully Charged" and keeps switching continuously. This switching happens after around every 10 seconds, but is not regular.

Is this normal behaviour? The continuous notification sounds are extremely annoying when I'm trying to get any work done.